# How to pass a dict to a python thread that can be changed from outside of thread without using queue

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary

I would like to have a shared dict between my threads without using Queue. I did it before by making thread with an object in python but now I want to make thread with just one function of object not all of it. my simplified code is as follow:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import threading
 import time


 class WebSocket(threading.Thread):
     def __init__(self, server=1, sock=1, address=1):
         self.s1=server
         self.s2=sock
         self.s3=address
         print "salam"


     def CheckThread(self):
         self.a={'1':1, '2':2}
         s=threading.Thread(target=self.SockFun, kwargs=self.a)
         s.deamon=True
         s.start()

         while(1):
             self.a['1']=self.a['1']+1
             time.sleep(1)

     def SockFun(self,**kwargs):
         pass

 class SimpleEcho(WebSocket):
     def SockFun(self,**kwargs):
         while(1):
             print kwargs
             time.sleep(1)

     def handleMessage(self):
         self.CheckThread()

 s=SimpleEcho()
 s.handleMessage()
```

my printed dict element '1' of kwargs does not increase as expected inside thread:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a threading issue.  self.a dictionary is not passed through via reference when you pass it in via kwargs, it gets copied in.

```
>>> mydict = {'foo': 'bar'}
>>> def func(**kwargs):
...     kwargs['hi'] = 'mom'
... 
>>> func(**mydict)
>>> print mydict
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `kwargs` mechanism causes the dict elements to be copied into `SimpleEcho`.  After they are there, changing the original doesn't make a difference to what is printed.  A quick way to see this is to change `print kwargs` to `print self.a`.

Alternatively you can change `kwargs=self.a` to `kwargs={"argh":self.a}`.  This way, `kwargs` will still be copied, but that copy will contain a reference to the original `self.a`.

And shouldn't you be using some kind of locking?

Answer (score 1):

The dictionnary is copied when you use the `**` syntax, this is why you cannot do that.

```
>>> foo = {'bar': 'baz'}
>>> def spam(**kwargs):
...     print(kwargs is foo)
... 
>>> spam(**foo)
False
```

You would have to use a mutable type, like a list, as an item of the dictionnary (you can do that because the copy is a shallow copy: it copies only the dictionnary and not its content).

```
>>> import time
>>> import threading
>>> def spam(**kwargs):
...     while True:
...         time.sleep(10)
...         print(kwargs['bar'][0])
... 
>>> foo = {'bar': ['baz']}
>>> threading.Thread(target=spam, kwargs=foo).start()
>>> baz

>>> foo['bar'][0] = 'qux'
>>> qux
qux
qux
```